# Access Issue and best function to accomplish task

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

New user here and I've read many threads, but can't seem to figure out the best way to accomplish my task.

Current Issue:I'm using a switch function in Access to accomplish my goal.  Here is what I have, but i'm getting a syntax error?

```
UPDATE all_rugs_prod
SET construction_facet =
    Switch(
        construction = Machine Woven, Machine Made,
        construction = Machine Made, Machine Made,
        construction = Printed, Printed,
        construction = Hand Hooked, Hand Hooked
        )
```

all_rugs_prod is Database, 
construction_facet is the field I want to value to be returned in, 
construction is the field it is going to search in.

I'm very new to all this so, i need as much help as I can get.....
Backdrop:I'm taking say database 1, then mapping/matching the fields to database 2.  database 2 has many other fields that require data to be popluated in that were added in database 2 that were added.

I created an Append database from database 1 into databas 2 and matched those fields that were appended from database 1 that match database 2.

My biggest issue is the fact that I need to normalize/map data in database 2. Example: in database 2 there is a field from database 1 that has many different text values.  I need to search that field and bring back a predetermined text value based on a predetermined list it would fit into.  So say in database 2.field7 the text is "aqua blue", I need to normalize/map it to return it to database 2.field8 "blue" and so on and so forth.  what is the best way to accomplish this.  The list in some cases of say various colors is very long. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error arises because you need to enclose literal strings in double quotes, e.g.

```
"Machine Woven"`
```

Otherwise each word separated by whitespace will be interpreted as a **field** (as opposed to a literal string), which, if not found in the source dataset, will result the fields being interpreted as parameters requiring a value to be supplied by the user; but more critically, this will result in too many arguments supplied to the `switch` function.

However, since you are only updating the value of records which contain the value `"Machine Woven"` in the `construction` field, your query could be simplified to:

```
update all_rugs_prod 
set construction_facet = "Machine Made" 
where construction = "Machine Woven"
```

For a situation in which many possible values in place of `"Machine Woven"` are being mapped to `"Machine Made"`, I would suggest creating a separate mapping table, e.g.:

`Mapping_Table`

```
+---------------------+--------------+
|      map_from       |    map_to    |
+---------------------+--------------+
| Machine Woven       | Machine Made |
| Machine Built       | Machine Made |
| Machine Constructed | Machine Made |
+---------------------+--------------+
```

And then use a simple update query with inner joins to the above mapping table to perform an implicit selection and update the new value, e.g.:

```sql
update 
    all_rugs_prod inner join mapping_table on
    all_rugs_prod.construction = mapping_table.map_from
set 
    all_rugs_prod.construction_facet = mapping_table.map_to
```

Comment: Yes the  " ", I forgot, i'm just so damn frusterated....haha......Ok, so I copied and pasted your option and it worked!!!  Now what if I have say 110 different options that =construction that need to be brought back as say "Machine Made"

Comment: Lee Mac I appreciate you.  I have tables built already as that was another road I traveled.  Now, let me see if I can figure out how to accomplish the above......

Comment: I created a join query, Join Properties= Left Table=all_rugs_prod/left column name=collection_facet Right Table=mapping fields construction/right column name=list, I selection option #2, I ran query and it works, but didn't poplulate all the fields.  SQL=update
  all_rugs_prod inner join mapping fields construction on
  all_rugs_prod.construction = mapping fields construction.list
set
  all_rugs_prod.construction_facet = mapping fields construction.facet   but i'm getting a "Syntax error in update statement" am I way off?

Comment: I have already provided the SQL for the query that you'll need to run, simply change the table names & field names to suit.

Comment: Thanks Lee worked like a charm, once i figured it out.  Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I'm very new to this language.

Comment: How do I write a script that will go search in a new .mdb file/table and map it from there and return to the table I want to populate, separate mdb file?  Mapping_Color(table in current .mdb file) Color_Facet sql=script=UPDATE all_rugs_prod INNER JOIN mapping_color ON all_rugs_prod.color = mapping_color.map_from SET all_rugs_prod.color_facet = mapping_color.map_to; New Mapping_Color (table created in a separte .mdb file) field names all the same.

Comment: I would suggest importing the table as a linked table from your other database file.

Comment: I had the table in the file, but my concern is when I add anything to the mapping tables as there are 9, i would have to then go into all the other database files (12) and add the item also.  I figured if the mapping table were in it's own file, the 12 dbs could go pull from there and if I delete or add anything, i'd be doing it in one place.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible idea - as I say, I would suggest importing such tables as linked tables from your single database file into each of the databases which will use the mapping table(s).